# JSF variable substitution with binding f:loadBundle

Tags: jsf, variables

I am trying to create a simple JSF application...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f"%>

<%@ page import="java.util.*"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Login</title>
<f:loadBundle var="Message" basename="bundle.Messages" />
</head>
<body>

    <f:view>
        <h:form id="loginForm">
            <h:message for="loginForm" />
            <br />
            <h:outputText value="#{Message.username_label}" ></h:outputText>
        </h:form>
    </f:view>
</body>
</html>
```

However, when I try to run the page in my browser, I get the value  `#{Message.username_label}`. Could someone please help me to understand why the value was not substituted into the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, EL doesn't get evaluated? This can happen when the `web.xml` is not properly declared conform *at least* Servlet 2.4 (for JSF 1.0/1.1) or 2.5 (for JSF 1.2) and/or your classpath is polluted with old versioned servletcontainer specific libraries.

Since you're using legacy JSP instead of its successor Facelets, I'll bet that you're using JSF 1.2 on a Servlet 2.5 container (such as Tomcat 6.0). In this case, you need to ensure that the `web.xml` is declared as follows:

```
<web-app 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5"
>
    <!-- Your config here -->
</web-app>
```

In addition, you also need to ensure that you don't have any servletcontainer specific libraries like `servlet-api.jar`, `j2ee.jar`, `javaee.jar`, `jsp-api.jar`, etc.. in your webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib` folder or, worse, in the `JRE/lib/ext` folder. Get rid of them, they are supposed to be supplied by the servletcontainer itself, not your webapp. The `/WEB-INF/lib` folder should contain only the JSF libraries and other libraries *specific* to the webapp itself.

Comment: Thank you. You are right. After I fixed to 2.5 (was <web-app version="2.4"
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" >) now working!

Comment: I had to change j2ee to javaee otherwise I got a "Non-whitespace characters are not allowed..." error in the web.xml.

Answer (score 0):

It is obvious to me.  is not a complied staememnt in java therfore the foundation of core cant encrypt it. the id is not being compiled because you have it in these <> do you know java?

Comment: Seems that non compiled only jsf part. Because if I insert simple jsp expression The time is now <%=getDate()%> - works.

Comment: try changing your outputText value

Comment: For literal value works. E.g. <h:outputText value="12431234234"></h:outputText>, output: 12431234234